# Does the square root of an input lie in the middle of that input?

Tags: algorithm, math, complexity-theory

I started reading the [Competitive Programmers Handbook](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf), and on page 20 the author writes about varying algorithmic complexity classes. When covering √, he writes:

> O(√) A square root algorithm is slower than O(log) but faster than O().
>
> A special property of square roots is that √ = /√, so the square root √ lies, in some sense, in the middle of the input.

I'm not entirely sure what he means by the middle of the input; is he just saying that √ is just somewhere between within the range [1, ]? If that's the case, log satisfies the same property, and I don't see why it's notable to bring up.

log = O(√) and √ = O(), so it is clear that O(√) lies between these two other well-defined classes, but I wonder if anyone has insight as to what the "middle of the input" is supposed to mean in this context.

Comment: My guess is if you consider the log of the complexity, you get log(n)/2 for sqrt(n), log(n) for n, so it's 'in the middle' of [0, log(n)]. You'd have to ask the author exactly what they mean, but it's probably that.

Comment: I heard that the real purpose of this book is to reduce competition in the workplace by teaching aspiring programmers bad habits, so that they become unemployable. Caveat emptor.

Comment: "the square root √ lies, in some sense, in the middle of the input"... is very sloppy thinking.

Answer (score 1):

"The middle of the input" here means a [geometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression) middle, i.e. when 1 and  are the first and third term in a geometric sequence, then √ is the second ("middle") one.

An example is where you divide an input array with  elements into √ buckets. By consequence of this "special" property of the square root, these buckets will each have approximately √ elements. See for example [jump search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_search). The choice of √ is a kind of optimum here: if you would divide the array into fewer buckets, you'd have more elements per bucket, and so more work to do. If you would divide the array into more buckets, you have more buckets to process, again increasing the work to do. So here you get a *feel* of this "middle".